# Trying to obtain the 2D version of a graph 3D graph

Tags: equation-solving, graphics

I'm trying to plot this function:

```
    f[x_, c_] := 
 527.5658823401758`*(1 - Erf[(2 x - 1)/(2^1.5)]) + 
  400.6284776272996`*(Erf[(2 (-c) + 1)/(2^1.5)] + 1)
```

I can plot it in 3D just fine. But I wanted a 2D version, holding `f[x,c]` constant and having `x` and `c` on the two axes. Basically cutting down the 3D graph for any value of `f`.

If anyone can help it would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot):

```
ContourPlot[f[x, c] == 1000, {x, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

or:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, c], {x, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5}, ContourLabels->True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!